# insert data from one table to a single column another table with no relation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to insert data into a table which is already having some data into it now a new column is added to the table and we need to insert/update the new column with values from another table.

```
create table target_tab (fname varchar2(20), acc_no number);

insert into target_tab values('Anybody',121);
insert into target_tab values('Somebody',122);
insert into target_tab values('Nobody',123);

alter table target_tab add sc_vlan varchar2(20);

create table source_tab (rsrc_nm varchar2(20));

insert into source_tab values ('2839_124');
insert into source_tab  values('2839_125');
insert into source_tab values('2839_126');
insert into source_tab values('2840_131');
insert into source_tab values('2841_132');
insert into source_tab values('2840_134');
insert into source_tab values('2840_127');
```

Now we need to insert the values of rsrc_nm column from source_tab to the scvlan column of the target_tab.

Note : we do not have any relationship between both tables and like we see in example that target_tab has less rows than source_tab then only row which are in target_tab should be insert/update with unique values from source_tab.
We can fetch any value from source_tab.

```
 declare 

  cursor c_1 is select rsrc_nm 
            from source_tab                                                                                                                                                   
              where rownum <= (select count(1)                                                                                                                                                 
               from target_tab);                                                                                                                                                                

  type t_tab is table of c_1%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  l_tab t_tab;

begin

  open c_1;
  fetch c_1 bulk collect into l_tab;
    for i in 1..l_tab.count
    loop  

      update target_tab set sc_vlan = l_tab(i).rsrc_nm
      where sc_vlan is null
      and rownum = 1;
      commit;
    exit when c_1%notfound;
  end loop;
  close c_1;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
    dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());    
end;
```

Comment: Your code and your table structures do not match, making it really unclear what you want to do.

Comment: Yes my code is not doing what my requirement is unfortunately !
But i do not see how table structure and code are not matching may be i am not clear with the requirement.
I have a table in which a new column has been added using alter statement now in this new column i need to populate values fetched from another table !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You could use `merge` like this:

```
merge into target_tab t
using (
  select s.rsrc_nm, t.rwd
    from (select row_number() over (order by acc_no)  rn, t.*, rowid rwd 
            from target_tab t) t
    join (select row_number() over (order by rsrc_nm) rn, s.* 
            from source_tab s) s
      on t.rn =s.rn
    ) s
on (t.rowid = s.rwd)
when matched then update set t.sc_vlan = s.rsrc_nm
```

Sort data in both tables on any columns, match them using `row_number` and update.

Comment: Thanks Ponder,
It is working let me try on original table with larger data set.
This statement is really nice !